# TypeScript type narrow on function parameters in callback based on other parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm dealing with classic node callbacks. Example:

```js
myFunction('foo', (err: Error|null, data?: Buffer) =>{
  if (err) {
    // typeof err is Error
    // typeof data is Buffer|undefined
  } else {
    // typeof err is null;
    // typeof data is Buffer|undefined;
  }
});
```

I am trying to define my own callback-accepting function `myFunction`. I am trying to achieve two things:

1. I want to be able to infer the type of `data` based on the type of `err`
2. I want to be able to implicitly infer the types of the input parameters

Example:

```js
// types of err and data are inferred from readFile
readFile('foo', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    // typeof err is Error
    // typeof data is undefined
  } else {
    // typeof err is null
    // typeof data is Buffer
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve either of these in current typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conventionally you'd use a single parameter of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) type instead of two union-typed parameters like `err` and `data` whose types are correlated to each other.

TypeScript really doesn't have much support for *correlated expressions*; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  That is, there isn't a great way to tell the compiler that while `err` is of type `Error | null` and while `data` is of type `Buffer | undefined`, some combinations of the types for `err` and `data` are not possible.  You can use [control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to check the type of `err`, but it will have no effect on the perceived type of `data`... the compiler erroneously assumes they are independent expressions.

Here is the closest I can get; it makes heavy use of [tuples in rest and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) and you really have to fight with the compiler to get it to sort of happen:

```
declare function myFunction(
  someString: string,
  someCallback: (...args: [Error, undefined] | [null, Buffer]) => void
): void;
```

The type of `someCallback` is a function of exactly two arguments, which are either the types `[Error, undefined]` or the typed `[null, Buffer]`.  Now you *can* call it with a two-param callback, but you'll run into the exact same problem you already have: checking `err` does not do anything to `data`:

```
// can't call it this way
myFunction("oops", (err, data) => {
  err; // Error | null
  data; // Buffer | undefined
  if (err) {
    data; // still Buffer | undefined 
  }
});
```

Instead you have to use rest parameters in the callback implementation also:

```
myFunction("foo", (...errData) => {
  if (errData[0]) {
    const [err, data] = errData;
    err; // Error
    data; // undefined
  } else {
    const [err, data] = errData;
    err; // null
    data; // Buffer
  }
});
```

That works because when you check `errData[0]` you are checking a single property of a tuple object, and the compiler will use control flow analysis to narrow `errData` to one of the two known types.  You can only break `errData` out into `err` and `data` *after* the check.

---

I strongly suggest you consider switching to a single discriminated union parameter in your callback.  Look at how easy the solution is:

```
type Param = { type: "Error"; err: Error } | { type: "Data"; data: Buffer };

declare function myFunction(
  someString: string,
  someCallback: (param: Param) => void
): void;

myFunction("foo", param => {
  if (param.type === "Error") {
    param.err; // Error
  } else {
    param.data; // Buffer
  }
});
```

That's pretty much exactly what you want, and no fighting necessary.

---

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgMwRATlAvFA3lARohEALigGdgUBLAOwHMoBfAbgFgAod6gQwFsJSwXAMbQAKgAsIAYQA2Ae1L9gASSldqAcQjAA6pWDjRAdzkAFLil7bUpbOyhQAJhCEyL0BHGpDglOdSgeEAAxLx8-agAKewcyOT4AZQoaWhJyKjoAGhiHUnjpLhkZXGEAaxJIgDpqi1pSEgBtAFEUFDkUTKgvZwQaCEcAXSgAHygG6jgizvgkVAGASgwAPigANzlKRxj5knXN1g42BwB6Y6ghdQByYHPCmSh9KANKWyMuEBig0O9ff0iAIjkcjApH+nUiqA6Ti4wC4i3QKywOSgkKYUFOUBabTQowmRWRjhhXDRGJmyBxXWoPT6WyOsUoCCgENaiyRdNi0NhJLO5EoRVgBFQI0p1Oo-SggF4NwD4e8iGDEGPMDjEMeIuKtoMA5Ld+Y9nq93p8QmFflF-gggWCmdVKpCACJE+GI5EMpl2okNAAMCzs7NiQn85DGkM6hNhQ0wbq5yIcqPRZyx7WjnOJcZFEF6YtpHIYKJkih9HIc-uogYaweT4ZRrXtUd9Mda3KgeJkSdDKdJgpQsvlivYcsO3D4AmE0FtLyEVB4NBh-QAqtQIgWnuBoOZLDwMNhl5ASP8Eyh-mjISR94xhThQDuoP8a1xD8mSGShcwYs5XO4oJ4fouvsaItFfTyRJkjoNIQNobJAPyNQihKIRyiZQR1xINdeEdNYNizKAdgw-Z2ENb5wj+M0LU6JDeGWJcHBdSJyJ4SpL2gdBmOvfd-lZJM6JtBtU33WVc3zNlCygLi20bJ8u19fsHAVA5+yAA)

Comment: Or may be even `type Param = Error | Buffer;`

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, the project I am working on has a lot of legacy code that cannot be converted to a discriminated union. But I will certainly keep it in mind for future work.