# Typescript passing union type to a function that only accept one of the types only

Tags: typescript, types, interface, refactoring

I have a function and interface that looks like this:

```js
export interface ISomeInterface {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  description?: string;
}

const callSomeApi = async (data: string | ISomeInterface, method: string): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    let result;
    switch (method) {
      case 'A':
        result = await customers.retrieve(data); // error retrieve here only accept string
        break;
      case 'B':
        result = await customers.create(data); // error create here only accept ISomeInterface
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
};
```

When I try to pass the union type to the customers function its giving the error cause of the union type.

Is there any workaround for me to conditionally pass the data with that union type to customers function without getting type error? (I can't change the type on retrieve and create since it's a SDK API)

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbkaoW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (There should be no undeclared values or types, for example... what is `customers`?) This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: you can always cast it to the type: `customers.retrieve(data as string)`

Comment: It seems like this question is nearly a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047629/typescript-type-narrow-on-function-parameters-in-callback-based-on-other-paramet), and if I translate the answer from that one here, I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/m3AE2w).  Could you look at the other question/answer and if you think there is a significant difference, edit this question to highlight the difference?